# Information about ethereum Wallet

Tags: ethereum

I am a bit new to all this. One of my clients needs a chrome extension like metamask. Creating the extension is not a problem but the main thing is how to i create a new ethereum address. My system will have many addresses and anyone can create his/her address and share there ethereum coins.

So can anyone guide me on this

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create your own address of course as many times as you want, its a random value generated by a 24 word mnemonic from English dictionary so the chances of running out of addresses are almost none.

To use Metamask you just download the extension make sure you are connected with Mainnet and create a simple account